# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\geq\frac{A^2}{n}$, where $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathbb Z^+,\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=A$.

Tags: inequality

Suppose we have $n$ positive integers $a_1,...,a_n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=A$. If we further assume $a_i<n$ for every $i$, then is the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\geq\frac{A^2}{n}$ true? If yes, how can we prove it?

Comment: This is just a simple case of Cauchy Shwartz inequality.

Comment: @Kavi: [Karl Hermann Amandus **Schwarz**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz) :)

Comment: Let $\bar{a} = \frac{A}{n}$, if one expand the non-negative expression below,
one obtain
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a_i - \bar{a})^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2 - \frac{A^2}{n} \ge 0$$

Comment: Thank you all for such simple and straight forward answers! :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use the QM-AM inequality. It makes perfect sense as each $a_{i}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. Then by QM-AM inequality, we have that
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i= 1}^{n} a_{i}^{2}}{n}} ~\geqslant~\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_{i}}{n}\\
\Leftrightarrow~ & \frac{\sum_{i= 1}^{n} a_{i}^{2}}{n} ~\geqslant~ \frac{A^2}{n^2}\\
\Leftrightarrow~ & {\sum_{i= 1}^{n} a_{i}^{2}} ~\geqslant~ \frac{A^2}{n} 
\end{align*}

Answer (score -1):

By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Jensen%27s%20inequality%2C%20named,proved%20by%20Jensen%20in%201906.), since $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^2>0$,
$$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2}n\ge \left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i}n\right)^2$$
, where $a_i\in\mathbb R,n\in\mathbb Z^+$.